# Como me conectar ao banco de dados via [WordPress] para consultar?

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, ajax, wordpress

Bom, eu tenho uma chamada `jQuery Ajax` no `header.php` do meu tema que está entrando num arquivo `PHP` na raiz do meu `Wordpress` e me retornando o `echo` de teste. Eu preciso que esse arquivo faça uma consulta ao `banco de dados` e me retorne algumas `ID's`.

Como posso fazer isso? O que eu desenvolvi até agora em relação ao arquivo `PHP` está abaixo mas não deu resultado. Eu acho que não estou usando a forma certa de me conectar ao banco de dados via `WordPress`.

```
<?php

// ... eu imagino que este include serve para 
// instaciar uma conexão com o banco de dados
require('./wp-blog-header.php');

if( isset($_POST['letra']) ){

    function retorna(){

        global $wpdb;

        // Recuperando o termo a ser filtrado no banco de dados
        $parametro = isset($_POST['letra']) ? $_POST['letra'] : null;

        // Recuperando os ID de todos os registros que respondem a pesquisa
        $pesquisas = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'professores'"); 

        // Por enquanto imprimindo estes valores
        foreach ( $pesquisas as $pesquisa ){ 

            print_r($pesquisa->ID);

        }   
    }

    retorna();  
}

?>
```

> Me aparecem aleatoriamente erros **404** e **500** mas os caminhos existem e as permissões estão corretas. Quando eu removo tudo de dentro da função e deixo um **echo** ela funciona.

Comment: Respondido ... Caso vc tenha interesse em fazer uma busca no WordPress e ainda usar uma requisição Ajax pra isso segue esse caminho ai que vc chega lá: http://pastebin.com/P65c3khd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para fazer consultas no wordpress primeiro você tem que dar um include nos arquivos de configuração e de db assim:

```
define( 'BLOCK_LOAD', true );
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-config.php' );
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-includes/wp-db.php' );
$wpdb = new wpdb( DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);
```

Depois você vai usar a variavel  `$wpdb` para fazer as consultas, exemplo:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_id = 1', OBJECT );
```

Para mais informações acesse: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: Você consegue avaliar e responder essa questão no stackoverflow americano: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/196143/how-to-solve-this-script-problem-in-theme-directory